# Rails app on Heroku - Issue with CORS

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cors

I have a Rails app on Heroku with this configuration:

```
module MyAppApi
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # other configs

    config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', 
            :headers => :any, 
            :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that any request returns with a 301 status. For example:

```
$ curl \
    -i -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -X OPTIONS 'http://myappapi.heroku.com/api/v1/resource.json'

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 17 May 2013 14:56:00 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://myappapi.heroku.com/api/v1/resource.json
```

Same response for GET, POST. Any ideas of what is happend here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `routes.rb` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting to *.heroku.com domain. Try to request to "*.herokuapp.com" instead

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h16-redirect-to-herokuappcom